# In-call status bar leaves offset

Tags: iphone, ios8

I have been trying to understand why my view controllers do not return to the correct position after the in-call status bar is turned off. When present all the content shifts down (some uiviews inside cells even shift incorrectly with respect to the cell but thats another issue), but also when the call is finished and the status bar closes, the content moves up but is still shifted down by maybe 20 pixels so it does not move back up by the same amount as it was shifted down. any ideas on how can this be avoided or fixed?